# Is It possible to use a React Awesome Builder (js) with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, react-query

I have to access a MySQL database, I have been told to use a [query builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-awesome-query-builder) to create a query to create a fresh list of filtered data. So, it looks like I can use SQL to filter the data, but I'm not sure how? Is this added to a fetch/Axios call? Do I use [Nodejs-MySql](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp)?

How do I implement a MySQL query when it's in this format?

```
"(t1.login = LOWER(user.firstName) AND stock = false AND slider = 35 AND (results.product = 'abc' AND results.score > 8) AND (cars.vendor = 'Toyota' AND cars.year >= 2010))"
```

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just a web interface to query databases, it is not a database.

Comment: react is client side, while mysql runs on the server side, so you need a server component that interact with mysql, be that in node.js or any other web development languages.

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find a solution. My problem was thinking that I could find a front-end solution to a backend problem.

What you can do is create a query using awesome react query builder, and copy the SQL as a WHERE.

The database I was using was on AdminMyPhp, and there's a SQL query section. so paste query and boom. you can test your query builder